# Converting float vector to double

Tags: c++, vector, double

Im rather new to c++ so forgive my ignorance on this.
Im trying to convert a double vector to a float vector for uses in certain cases( im aware there is a precision loss).
The structure of the vectors is simply,

```
struct Dvector
{
public:

double X;
double Y;
double Z;
```

Is there a simple function to create that can be called in multiple areas to convert it to a float structure such as?

```
   struct Fvector
{
public:

float X;
float Y;
float Z;
```

Comment: This should be tagged with [tag:c++].

Comment: No, you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For converting Fvector to Dvector you can use the [user-defined conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). Take a look at the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Dvector
{
public:
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;
};

struct Fvector
{
public:
    float X;
    float Y;
    float Z;

    explicit operator Dvector()
    {
        Dvector d;
        d.X = static_cast<double>(X);
        d.Y = static_cast<double>(Y);
        d.Z = static_cast<double>(Z);

        return d;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Fvector f = {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f};
    Dvector d = static_cast<Dvector>(f);
    std::cout << d.X << d.Y << d.Z;
    return 0;
}
```